# Can d3 intelligently choose an appropriate number format?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, format, axis, scientific-notation

I have a chart that displays the frequency of names in the population over time, just one name at a time that the user selects. For, say, "John", the maximum value is 0.08 (8% of all names), so it's no problem to display the percents on the y axis. For the name "Stevens," meanwhile, the peak value is 0.000014984.

I don't want to have a 60px left margin if I can avoid it, so I'd prefer for these small numbers to be in scientific notation.

Right now I have a hacky solution:

```
y.tickFormat(function(d) {
    if (d == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (d > 0.001) { // arbitrary cutoff
        return d3.format(",.1%")(d);
    }
    return d3.format(".2e")(d * 100) + "%";
});
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this, where numbers from 1-99, for example, don't get "e0" appended?

Comment: Yes, you can use a multi-scale format, see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176

Comment: Thank you! Should have known